# r lldb debugger with R fails

Tags: r, lldb

Just starting to attempt to use lldb debugger with R following the steps in this [url] [1](https://blog.davisvaughan.com/2019/04/05/debug-r-package-with-cpp/). I don't get very far. In a terminal window, `R -d lldb` opens an lldb prompt. When I put `run` into that prompt I get the following error message.

```
error: process exited with status -1 (attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process.  Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries, when the attach failed.  The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely have logged an informative message about why it was denied.))
```

In the console app I see a debugserver error the says "Attach failed" and another one with the error message. And just before these is this one.

```
error: [LaunchAttach] END (90757) MachProcess::AttachForDebug failed to start exception thread attaching to pid 90756: unable to start the exception thread
```

But they don't provide me any guidance on what to do.

I'm using a new MacBook Pro with Apple Silicon and the version of R for arch 64.

Answer (score 0):

The OS will only allow the debugger to attach to binaries that have marked themselves with the right entitlement, indicating they opt-in to being debugged.  Most groups do not mark their release binaries as debuggable.  Presumably that's true of the binary you are debugging.  You can use the `codesign -d --entitlements - <Binary>` to check the entitlements on this binary.  To be debuggable it has to have the get_task_allow entitlement set to true.

Comment: When I run R -d lldb, I get the message "target create "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R"
Current executable set to '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R' (arm64)"

When I return to the shell and run " codesign -d --entitlements - /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R" I get several key values but none on entitlements.

Comment: Though the entitlement to allow debugging is a boolean, it also defaults to "don't allow" if it isn't present.  I don't know how hard it is to build R, but presumably there is a debuggable configuration if you do build it by hand.  That might be your best option.